# I am having difficulties while deploying wagtail app in cPanel

Tags: python, django, cpanel, wagtail

I am getting this error while deploying wagtail app in cpanel

```
Collecting pillow==8.4.0
  Downloading Pillow-8.4.0.tar.gz (49.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 49.4/49.4 MB 11.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pillow
  Building wheel for pillow (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [135 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PyAccess.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/features.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/BlpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMorph.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_version.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PdfParser.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      copying src/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/PIL
      running egg_info
      writing src/Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to src/Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching '*.c'
      warning: no files found matching '*.h'
      warning: no files found matching '*.sh'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.appveyor.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.clang-format'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.editorconfig'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching '.readthedocs.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      no previously-included directories found matching '.ci'
      adding license file 'LICENSE'
      writing manifest file 'src/Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      building 'PIL._imaging' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/libImaging
      building 'PIL._imagingtk' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/Tk
      building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
      building 'PIL._imagingmath' extension
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-8euawa9w/pillow_e5dab49ab2624377ae6fbeb92c03879a -I/usr/include -I/home/missztoi/virtualenv/demo.codingrites/3.8/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/Tk/tkImaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/Tk/tkImaging.o
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-8euawa9w/pillow_e5dab49ab2624377ae6fbeb92c03879a -I/usr/include -I/home/missztoi/virtualenv/demo.codingrites/3.8/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/_imagingft.o
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -DHAVE_XCB -DPILLOW_VERSION=\"8.4.0\" -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-8euawa9w/pillow_e5dab49ab2624377ae6fbeb92c03879a -I/usr/include -I/home/missztoi/virtualenv/demo.codingrites/3.8/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/_imaging.o
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-8euawa9w/pillow_e5dab49ab2624377ae6fbeb92c03879a -I/usr/include -I/home/missztoi/virtualenv/demo.codingrites/3.8/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/_imagingmath.o
      building 'PIL._imagingmorph' extension
      gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -g -std=c99 -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/tmp/pip-install-8euawa9w/pillow_e5dab49ab2624377ae6fbeb92c03879a -I/usr/include -I/home/missztoi/virtualenv/demo.codingrites/3.8/include -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c src/_imagingmorph.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/src/_imagingmorph.o
      error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pillow
  Running setup.py clean for pillow
Failed to build pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on who is providing your cPanel hosting, it may be possible to install Wagtail and its dependencies - but I wouldn't bet on it.

The message above indicates that Python is trying to install the image processing library Wagtail needs. It is not finding a pre-built binary distribution for the underlying operating system for your hosting service and so is trying to build the required library - but is not allowed to. You do not have the permissions needed to use the compiler (command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed: Permission denied).

Your next step needs to be contacting your hosting service and asking if they can help you install Pillow. If they say no, I suggest you try one of the [hosting options suggested in the docs](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/advanced_topics/deploying.html). Or, [CodeRed](https://www.codered.cloud/) and [Torchbox](https://torchbox.com/wagtail-cms/hosting-application-support/) both provide managed hosting services.